# Lubuntu 20.04LTS freezing with Displayport drivers

Tags: ubuntu, displayport, docking-station, lubuntu

I've got a Dell Inspiron 3510 and a Dell D3100 docking station, to which I want to run dual monitors.  I have the Displayport drivers installed, configured everything and THOUGHT I was golden, but repeatedly now, after 5-10 minutes of use, the system locks up completely.  No mouse movement, no keyboard, the only way to recover is to long press the power until the system shuts down.

Note, I am using a CableMatters DP-to-HDMI adapter, so that I can plug in the monitor.

Interestingly, I connected the monitor back up by itself to the HDMI port in the laptop and the same thing still happened.  So I uninstalled the driver software completely.

Anyone know what I can do to fix this?  I tried following Displayport's instructions for freezes on Ubuntu 18.04 but that didn't help.  Anyone else have this issue?  Anyone else know what I can do?

Comment: *I connected the monitor back up by itself to the HDMI port in the laptop and the same thing still happened. So I uninstalled the driver software completely.* So, should we assume this didn't happen again after uninstalling the Displaylink drivers? (Not displayport, you're confused about that, DP, like HDMI, DVI or any other "port" doesn't need user installed drivers; drivers are needed for proprietary DisplayLink technology that often comes integrated in many USB docks). Please [edit] the question accordingly and while at that add hardware specifications and whether or not you updated UEFI.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Great question.  No, as it turns out, it seems the issue is happening no matter what.  I've removed everything except the laptop's power cord, even the USB mouse and keyboard...and it's still happening.  So I guess this is a different issue from one specific to Displayport, unless perhaps it's connected to the fact that I changed the Secure Boot (turned it off) in order to more easily run the driver.  I recently turned it back ON again, but that seems not to have helped either.  I'm now wondering if this is a hardware issue with the computer itself, maybe?  Sigh.  Thank you again!

Comment: Secure Boot has nothing to do with it. And again, DP (DisplayPort) is a connection, **DisplayLink** is a chip that enables video over USB, something that is probably doomed to history's trash can now that USB-C can do that natively.